# Combine two regex condition using or

Tags: javascript, regex

I have one regex to check below conditions in javascript

1. at-least 1 number
2. could be alphanumeric
3. special character allowed would be - , space, #

   ```
   var regex= new RegExp (/^(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d #-]+$/);
   ```

   This works fine.But I need to modify condition 1 as

   1. **at-least 1 number or 1 character**(2nd 3rd condition are unaltered)
      Is it possible to do it without using OR of regex.I even tried with OR attribute but found no luck.

Comment: Do you understand how what you have works? It is very easy to modify it as required.

Comment: I am not expert of regex but understands regex I used,tried to modify,no success.

Comment: Is `12345` allowed? Or is it needed to have at least one alpha?

Comment: That did not answer my question. And really, you don't have to be an expert to change `\d` to `[\da-zA-Z]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily put it in a character class in the first requirement:

```
var regex= new RegExp (/^(?=.*[\dA-Za-z])[a-zA-Z\d #-]+$/);
                                 ^^^^^^
```

Comment: @sandy You're welcome! Don't forget that the character classes can be used as 'or' sometimes :)